# call window.frames inside loop "for"

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, frames

I have a function that receives an array with the names of functions that I want execute:

```
function ExecutaFnParent(numFunc)
{
    for (i = 0; i < numFunc.length; i++)
    {
        window.frames.iprincipal.numFunc[i](1);
    }
}
```

but that does not work. How can I pass `numFunc` with the value of the function?

"numFuncio" is the value of the function inside iframe "iprincipal"

Comment: Please show an example of code where you call this function.

Comment: var numFunc= new Array();
numFunc[0]="nomFuncion";
parent.ExecutaFnParent(numFunc);

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
window.frames.iprincipal.numFunc[i](1);
```

with

```
window.frames.iprincipal[numFunc[i]](1);
```

Comment: thanks!!! it's works!!! but instead window.frames.iprincipal[numFunc[i]](1); i want window.frames.iprincipal[numFunc[i]](params);
How I can it?

Comment: Is `params` an array of arguments that you want to pass to the function?

Comment: Thank's everybody, i found a solution

the final result...

for (i = 0; i < numFunc.length; i++)
 { 
     if(params[i])
  {
   window.frames.iprincipal[numFunc[i]](params[i]);
  }
  else
  {
   window.frames.iprincipal[numFunc[i]]();
  }

 }
params[i] contains the params of the numFunc function..

Comment: If this is the correct answer, just press the check mark next to it.